# Scroll window to element/component in angular

Tags: angular

I can use the following to scroll to the top of a page:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

How can I scroll to a specific element?  I'm using Angular, so don't want to use the scroll2 JQuery library, and all the questions/answers here relate to angularjs

Comment: I guess this is for a phone?

Comment: It's mainly for desktop, list on the LHS, detail on the RHS, if you click an item half way down the list, the detail updates out of your view.  But you can't scroll to top because of the way the divs are stacked on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add a @ViewChild in your component and use **.nativeElement.focus()**

***component html :***

```
<div #mydiv ></div>
```

***component ts :***

```
 export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('mydiv') myDiv: any;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myDiv.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything in Ng7